# Flutter Error: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug

Tags: flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code, build.gradle

I reinstall my flutter and trying to load my app again, but I am having trouble loading it up. I have tried for three days, even reinstalling my window and all program again, but I did not have any luck. Anyone can help me with this, please?

you can access my files on https://github.com/bagmk/StartUp_Project/tree/master/fluttershare-master

main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/home.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Barter',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme:
          ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple, accentColor: Colors.teal),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: fluttershare
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: 1.0.5
  firebase_core : 1.0.3
  image_picker: 0.7.4
  firebase_storage: 8.0.3
  firebase_auth: 1.0.3
  google_sign_in: 5.0.2
  geolocator: 5.0.1
  uuid: 3.0.4
  image: 3.0.2
  animator: 0.1.4
  cupertino_icons: 1.0.2
  path_provider: 2.0.1
  firebase_messaging: 9.1.1
  timeago: 3.0.2
  cached_network_image: 
  flutter_svg:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
    - family: Signatra
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Signatra.ttf
  assets:
    - assets/images/google_signin_button.png
    - assets/images/upload.svg
    - assets/images/search.svg
    - assets/images/activity_feed.svg
    - assets/images/no_content.svg
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

app/build.Gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {

    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.test.fluttershare"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.0.0')
    
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Debug console

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Error log

```
[        ] [  +15 ms] Done persisting file store
[        ] [   +2 ms] Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
[        ]            #0      KernelSnapshot.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/common.dart:291:7)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #1      _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:828:9)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #2      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #3      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:766:32)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #4      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #5      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:766:32)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #6      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #7      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:766:32)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #8      FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:595:16)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #9      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:318:32)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #10     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #11     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #12     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #13     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #14     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #15     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #16     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #17     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #18     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] [   +4 ms] 
[        ]            #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
[        ]            #1      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:335:7)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] [  +10 ms] "flutter assemble" took 12,491ms.
[  +62 ms] [  +83 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 82ms
[        ] [   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] [        ] exiting with code 1
[        ] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease FAILED
[        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[        ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] 1 actionable task: 1 executed
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * Where:
[        ] Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
[        ] > Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 16s
[ +579 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... (completed in 17.0s)
[   +4 ms] "flutter apk" took 17,574ms.
[   +4 ms] Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
[   +1 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:464:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:231:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:105:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[ +103 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 98ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.631], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed this website

https://www.programmersought.com/article/68154823442/

It was the from the prior error, so I have fixed that, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

1. First delete your `build` folder
2. Clean Flutter by using `flutter clean`
3. Then click on `pub get` in your `pubspec.yaml` file
4. Build again your project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue you are facing. What I did is this. First, I ran the code in verbose mode, I ran my application again to see the error. I noticed that in my `./android/app/` there was a build directory that shouldn't be there. This directory created a new looping instance of a file. This was the error stoping my code from working. So I deleted the `./android/app/build` folder and the .gradle folder in `./android/` directory. Then ran `flutter run`. This solved my issue.

Basically, you want to run a more detailed report so you can see where the error is coming from then solve it. But most times deleting the build and re-running your application should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by

first, delete android folder

then, run commmand `flutter create .` to recreate the android folder again

then, just modify some of the changes or just follow the git changes

Note: this solution is should be follow if `flutter clean` does not help

Answer (score -1):

Flutter 2.2 enables the sound null safety feature by default.
In my case, I have project migrated to null-safety support, but some project dependencies haven't been migrated. So, I have to specify the `--no-sound-null-safety` argument to make the app run and build (as one of the working solutions).

If you have the same, probably, it will help and to you:

```
flutter build apk --no-sound-null-safety
```

PS: I specified `--no-sound-null-safety` as run arguments in my IDE but forgot to specify it on `flutter build` call in the console.
Idk why but `flutter build` doesn't tell clearly that problem was because of that missing argument.